# am working on nodejs project with docker and sequelize, i am getting the error: cannot read property toString of undefined

Tags: sequelize.js

here is my screenshot of my exception:

[image: this is my stacktrace]

below is my models:

```
module.exports.up = (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.UUID
    },
    email: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    passwordHash: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.CHAR(64)
    },
    createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    deletedAt: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
}, {
    charset:"utf8"
} 
);
```

};

module.exports.down = queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable("users");

```
module.exports.up = (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
return queryInterface.createTable('userSession', {
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.UUID
    },           

    userId: {
        references: "id",
        model:"users"
    },

    passwordHash: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.CHAR(64)
    },
    createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    deletedAt: {
        allowNull: true,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
}, {
    charset:"utf8"
} 
);
```

};

module.exports.down = queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable("userSession");

i cant figure out whats wrong, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following parts of migrations:

1. Sequelize is not defined here. Change it to `DataTypes`.

```
    email: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
```

2. Reference is not defined correctly in userSession table. It should be defined like this:

```
      userId: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          references: {
            model: 'users',
            key: 'id',
          },
      },
```

3. Last but not least, the id field of `users` table should be defined as the primary key. Otherwise you can not be able to assign it as a foreign key in userSession table. Hence in users table, add the property `primaryKey: true`.

```
      id: {
          primaryKey: true,
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.UUID
      },
```

So the migrations scripts would look like this in the end:

**For users table:**

```
module.exports.up = (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
  return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
          primaryKey: true,
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.UUID
      },
      email: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          unique: true
      },
      passwordHash: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.CHAR(64)
      },
      createdAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      deletedAt: {
          allowNull: true,
          type: DataTypes.DATE
      }
  }, {
      charset:"utf8"
  }
  );
};

module.exports.down = queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable("users");
```

**For userSession table:**

```
module.exports.up = (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
  return queryInterface.createTable('userSession', {
      id: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.UUID
      },
      userId: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          references: {
            model: 'users',
            key: 'id',
          },
      },
      passwordHash: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.CHAR(64)
      },
      createdAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      deletedAt: {
          allowNull: true,
          type: DataTypes.DATE
      }
  }, {
      charset:"utf8"
  }
  );
};

module.exports.down = queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable("userSession");
```

P.S: Delete old tables along with SequelizeMeta in your database and then run migrations.

Comment: does it mean i must change the whole thing since the function its taking sequelize and if i change that it will require me to change the whole body?

Comment: No the function is taking DataTypes as a second argument, so just replace Sequelize with DataTypes (no need to change anything else)

Comment: Oh I spotted out some more mistakes. The reference was defined incorrectly in userSession and also you didn't assign `primaryKey:true` to the id field in users table. I edited the answer. Have a look at updated one.

Comment: now its saying : ERROR: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Have you copy paste the above two scripts I added? I tried and they are working.

Comment: yes i copy pasted, can there be a problem with my .sequelize file?, because i did the exct above

Comment: or probable version difference of sequelize

Comment: My sequelize version is `5.21.7`

Comment: Had you deleted  `users`, `userSession` and `SequelizeMeta` table from the db (if existed). run the migrations after deleting tables.

Comment: i did sudo docker-compose down and sudo docker-compose up then tried again, actually this is my first project to sequelize and docker so i am really not sure how to go by deleting the sequelize metadata, its still giving error

Comment: i deleted my contatiners and did docker volume prune, after that i recreated them using docker-compose --build when i start again yarn db:migrate it still says cannot add foreign key constraint and in the vscode console it says "Aborted connection 6 to db: 'db' user: 'root' host: '172.18.0.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)"

Comment: if you dont mind can i please see how your docker compose file looks like but i think this has to do with my ram

Comment: I don't think you should receive this foreign key error with this configuration. May be the problem is with the execution order. Let's debug this in a following way: i) Just create only one file for migration which is creating user table ii) Run migrations iii) Create another file for userSession table iv) Run migration again